# Insert items in a table using a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I've deleted an old, badly worded question and am reposting to not waste anyone's time.

I'm trying to query stuff from two tables, rooms and items.  Then in a nested loop, create an entry in a 3rd table using info from the first two.

'For each room, insert ALL the standard items'

```
<?php
mysql_connect("******", "****", "******") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("MaintenanceTracking") or die(mysql_error());// Check connection

//collect standard items names
$stditemdata = 'SELECT * FROM `StandardItems`';
$itemresult = mysql_query($stditemdata) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error());
$itemarray = mysql_fetch_array( $itemresult ));

//collect room info
$roomdata = 'SELECT * FROM `Rooms`';
$roomresult = mysql_query($roomdata) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error());

//repeat for each room
while($room = mysql_fetch_array( $roomresult )) 
{
    //repeat for each item
 for ($i = 0; $i <= count($itemarray); $i++)
   {
      mysqlquery("INSERT into Items 
      (ItemNumber, Name, LocationCode)
      VALUES 
      (NULL, $itemarray['Name'], $room['LocationCode'])");
   }
}
?>
```

I'm pretty new to php and must appologize that the syntax sometimes gets me stumped...I notoriously miss the semi-colon at the ends of rows, for example.

A million thanks in advance to anyone and everyone who can help me out.

kindest regards

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It would be easy for us to decipher, if you are able to show us your datadump, and may be a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) would be great! :)

Comment: You probably need quotes around your variables in the query.

Comment: Sorry everyone.  I didn't really ask a question in there.  I just can't get it to run.  I'm coding in Bluefish and it doesn't help much with the typos.  I'm just not sure what I'm missing to get it to run.

Comment: In case anyone else dives in...I've figured it out.  I backed up and started posting all the data to tables until I was sure my loops were working properly and then dumped the table and stuffed it into an INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
  mysqlquery("INSERT into Items 
  (ItemNumber, Name, LocationCode)
  VALUES 
  (NULL, $itemarray['Name'], $room['LocationCode'])");
```

It should be

```
  mysql_query("INSERT into `Items` 
  (`ItemNumber`, `Name`, `LocationCode`)
  VALUES 
  (NULL, $itemarray['Name'], $room['LocationCode'])");
```

You use **mysqlquery** instead of **mysql_query**

To avoid duplication of mysql-reserved names (f.e. date, table etc) use this syntax

```
`column_name` or `table_name`
```

UPDATE

oh.. i miss! look, you try to write some strings into DB here

```
  mysql_query("INSERT into `Items` 
  (`ItemNumber`, `Name`, `LocationCode`)
  VALUES 
  (NULL, $itemarray['Name'], $room['LocationCode'])");
```

All strings in queries must be concluded in quotes single **'** or double **"**, so your query should looks like

```
  mysql_query("INSERT into `Items` 
  (`ItemNumber`, `Name`, `LocationCode`)
  VALUES 
  (NULL, \"$itemarray['Name']\", \"$room['LocationCode']\")");
```

(i use \ symbol before " to escape quote), but i suggest you to use syntaxys like this:

```
  mysql_query("INSERT into `Items` 
  (`ItemNumber`, `Name`, `LocationCode`)
  VALUES 
  (NULL, '".$itemarray['Name']."', '".$room['LocationCode']."')");
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's the kind of typo I have trouble spotting.  I still can't get it to run though and won't even start.  I think my only option is to remove a bunch of the loop stuff and get it running one step at a time.  I figured it was close enough to my other working code to not have to go through this.

Comment: `$itemarray = mysql_fetch_array( $itemresult ));`
you use one opening bracket and 2 closing, replace it by `$itemarray = mysql_fetch_array( $itemresult );`